# Increase in another audio player progress when playing another audio jquery ui jplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, audio, jplayer

Hi I have a audio gallery in which there are numbers of audios. I am embeding jquery ui jplayer plugin to player audio. I am using foreach loops with each audio player to display. Below is my code.

```
 <?php
            $sql="select * from sn_audio where publish=1 order by audioId desc limit 2";
            $data = $db->get_data($sql);
            // var_dump($data);
            if($data['count']>0){
                $i = 1;
                foreach($data['results'] as $value){
                    $i++;
             ?>
            <div class="audio-player">

               <p><?php echo $value['title']; ?></p>

               <div class="pull-left">
                <div id="jquery_jplayer_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="jp-jplayer"></div>

                <div id="jp_container_<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <div class="jp-gui ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="jp-play ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play ui-icon ui-icon-play" tabindex="1" title="play">play</a></li>
                            <li class="jp-pause ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause ui-icon ui-icon-pause" tabindex="1" title="pause">pause</a></li>
                            <li class="jp-stop ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop ui-icon ui-icon-stop" tabindex="1" title="stop">stop</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="jp-progress-slider"></div>
                        <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                        <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                        <div class="jp-clearboth"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-no-solution">
                        <span>Update Required</span>
                        To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
                    </div>
                </div><!--jplayer container ends-->
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                   <a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH;?>audios/audioGallery/<?php echo $value['audio'];?>" title="Download" class="text-center download">
                        <img src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH;?>images/download.png" class="center-block" alt="">
                        Download
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div><!--audio player-->

            <!-- script -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            /*
 * jQuery UI ThemeRoller
 *
 * Includes code to hide GUI volume controls on mobile devices.
 * ie., Where volume controls have no effect. See noVolume option for more info.
 *
 * Includes fix for Flash solution with MP4 files.
 * ie., The timeupdates are ignored for 1000ms after changing the play-head.
 * Alternative solution would be to use the slider option: {animate:false}
 */

var myPlayer = $("#jquery_jplayer_<?php echo $i; ?>"),
    myPlayerData,
    fixFlash_mp4, // Flag: The m4a and m4v Flash player gives some old currentTime values when changed.
    fixFlash_mp4_id, // Timeout ID used with fixFlash_mp4
    ignore_timeupdate, // Flag used with fixFlash_mp4
    options = {
        ready: function (event) {
            // Hide the volume slider on mobile browsers. ie., They have no effect.
            if(event.jPlayer.status.noVolume) {
                // Add a class and then CSS rules deal with it.
                $(".jp-gui").addClass("jp-no-volume");
            }
            // Determine if Flash is being used and the mp4 media type is supplied. BTW, Supplying both mp3 and mp4 is pointless.
            fixFlash_mp4 = event.jPlayer.flash.used && /m4a|m4v/.test(event.jPlayer.options.supplied);
            // Setup the player with media.
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "<?php echo ROOT_PATH;?>audios/audioGallery/<?php echo $value['audio'];?>",
                m4a: "<?php echo ROOT_PATH;?>audios/audioGallery/<?php echo $value['audio'];?>",
                oga: "<?php echo ROOT_PATH;?>audios/audioGallery/<?php echo $value['audio'];?>"
            });
        },

        play: function() { // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together.
            $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        },

        timeupdate: function(event) {
            if(!ignore_timeupdate) {
                myControl.progress.slider("value", event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute);
            }
        },
        volumechange: function(event) {
            if(event.jPlayer.options.muted) {
                myControl.volume.slider("value", 0);
            } else {
                myControl.volume.slider("value", event.jPlayer.options.volume);
            }
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "m4a, oga, mp3",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_<?php echo $i; ?>",
        wmode: "window"
    },
    myControl = {
        progress: $(options.cssSelectorAncestor + " .jp-progress-slider"),
        volume: $(options.cssSelectorAncestor + " .jp-volume-slider")
    };

// Instance jPlayer
myPlayer.jPlayer(options);

// A pointer to the jPlayer data object
myPlayerData = myPlayer.data("jPlayer");

// Define hover states of the buttons
$('.jp-gui ul li').hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
);

// Create the progress slider control
myControl.progress.slider({
    animate: "fast",
    max: 100,
    range: "min",
    step: 0.1,
    value : 0,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var sp = myPlayerData.status.seekPercent;
        if(sp > 0) {
            // Apply a fix to mp4 formats when the Flash is used.
            if(fixFlash_mp4) {
                ignore_timeupdate = true;
                clearTimeout(fixFlash_mp4_id);
                fixFlash_mp4_id = setTimeout(function() {
                    ignore_timeupdate = false;
                },1000);
            }
            // Move the play-head to the value and factor in the seek percent.
            myPlayer.jPlayer("playHead", ui.value * (100 / sp));
        } else {
            // Create a timeout to reset this slider to zero.
            setTimeout(function() {
                myControl.progress.slider("value", 0);
            }, 0);
        }
    }
});

// Create the volume slider control
myControl.volume.slider({
    animate: "fast",
    max: 1,
    range: "min",
    step: 0.01,
    value : $.jPlayer.prototype.options.volume,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        myPlayer.jPlayer("option", "muted", false);
        myPlayer.jPlayer("option", "volume", ui.value);
    }
});
</script>
<!-- script -->
            <?php }} ?>
```

But when I ever I play one audio then there is progress in another audio player which had came from foreach loop from database.

Comment: because you are using single variable to store the object instance which will be overridden each time the player is initialized. so at the end `myPlayer` will have the last player instance and will update only that.

Comment: What would be the work around to solve the problem. Do I need to make variable myplayer1, myplayer2 and so on in loop. thank you

Comment: can use an object to store all the instances and use the index to map the player with the instance for later use

Comment: Please a sample code for the process.